# Protractor how to check if attribute exists?

Tags: javascript, protractor

How to check if attribute exists in protractor? I have element

```
<input class="x" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="undefined" disabled name="checkboxname1" tabindex="0" aria-label="">
```

I want to check if disabled attribute is present.

I tried that:

```
const isDisabled: boolean = await field.getAttribute('disabled') === null ? true : false;
```

but this checks the value of this attribute, not if it's present.

Answer (score 2):

In my test I wait until attribute is not present.
I did it by code

```
await browser.wait(async () => await this.loginButton.getAttribute('disabled') === null);
```

when you call `getAttribute()` for nonexistent attribute, it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

You can find whether an element is Disabled or Not using elementToBeClickable() method.

**CODE:**

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedCondiditons;
var field=/*input filed locator*/ 

expect(EC.elementToBeClickable(field)).toBe(false)

/*EC.elementToBeClickable(field) - return true if element is enabled or 
/*false*
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Got "Expected Function to be true/false." failure

Answer (score 0):

The CSS reference for element that has a particular attribute is `[attribute]`. So you can do something like this:

```
const disabledCheckbox1 = '#checkbox1[disabled]';    
const isCheckbox1Disabled = await $(disabledCheckbox).isPresent();
```

where `$(...)` is a shortcut for `element.by(css(...))`

Or if you want to make it more generic:

```
const element = '#checkbox1';
const attribute = 'disabled';
const isElementDisabled = await $(`${element}[${attribute}]`).isPresent();
```

Hope this helps!

Here's a great reference to various CSS selectors magic you can do: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp